# How can I grab the last element of a List of string arrays?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

lstArray is a list of string arrays:

```
List<string[]> lstArray = new List<string[]>();
```

Obviously its size varies. In the sample below it has two elements; first one has 4, second one has 5 items in it.
Last item always refers to a table name (tblPerson, tblCompany, etc.). That's what I want to collect.
It might be 4th, 5th, or even 8th item sometimes. I will have another list of string which is filled with these table names.

[image: lstArray elements]

lstArray[0]:

[image]

lstArray[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Dnt.png):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's always the last element, you can use this:

```
var lastElements = lstArray.Select(e => e.Last());
```

If some of the arrays have zero elements, you might also use:

```
var lastElements = lstArray.Select(e => e.LastOrDefault());
```

In which case you could end up with some `null` entries.  Another way to avoid that might be something like:

```
var lastElements = lstArray.Select(e => e.Count == 0 ? string.Empty : e.Last());
```

This would give you `string.Empty` instead of `null` for empty arrays, which would be somewhat less error-prone for consuming code.

Comment: You could include a .Where to filter empty arrays, but besides that your answer gets my vote.

Answer (score 2):

The following will return the last element on `lstArray`:

```
var lastElement = lstArray.Last();
```

However what you want is the collection of all the last elements of the string arrays contained in `lstArray`, which you can obtain so:

```
var lastElements = lstArray.Select(i => i.Last())
```

Comment: This would provide the last array in the list, not a list of the last element in each array.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?:

```
List<string[]> lstArray = new List<string[]>();
var result = lstArray.Select(a=>a.Last())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastElement = lstArray.Last().Last() //this will give the last element of last array

var lastElement = lstArray.Select(sublist => sublist.Last()); //this will give last element of each array in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the List last item

```
int len = strList.length();
String strArr[] = strList.get(len);
```

Get String Array last element i.e. last string

```
String str = strArr[strArr.size()-1]
```